# Google Analytics for Mobile (__utm.gif) and multiple sub domains

Tags: google-analytics

On a mobile site I am working on, I use the server side call to `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sa&utmn=1527287986&utmhn=<removed>&utmr=<removed>&utmp=<removed>&utmac=<removed>&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B&utmvid=<removed>&utmip=`

(ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites)

This site sits on m.myhostname.com

There is a main website on www.myhostname.com

As such, the main website, which uses the clientside Javascript ga.js, has `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.myhostname.com']);` set.

Do I need to do something similar on the server side call, so that visitors are tracking moving between the domains?

I can't find any documentation about it needing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up cross domain tracking on your site and put the javascript code on every page in both subdomains:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Alternatively you can also set up seperate profiles in the same GA account and filter out traffic going to each sub domain so that you can view the traffic in that manner.
http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034832&topic=1034830&ctx=topic

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the server side code, as detailed in the question.